# How to write Redirect rule for redirecting one old url to new url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My sample URL:

> http://example.com/damage_restoration_blog/damage-restoration-blog.php%3Fentry_id%3D1342577058%26title%3Dblack-mold-use-caution-when-removing

I need to redirect to this new URL:

> http://example.com/damage_restoration_blog/damage-restoration-blog.php?entry_id=1342577058&title=black-mold-use-caution-when-removing

I tried to do it again and again, but it's not working for me. I am expecting expert suggestion for redirecting this URL.

Comment: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/redirection/ this might help

Comment: CAn you show what you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /damage_restoration_blog/damage-restoration-blog.php%3Fentry_id%3D1342577058%26title%3Dblack-mold-use-caution-when-removing http://example.com/damage_restoration_blog/damage-restoration-blog.php?entry_id=1342577058&title=black-mold-use-caution-when-removing
```

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php

Comment: Hey Duncan, This is not a valid process with me .htaccess file cos after giving this file my website is being unaccessible and showing me 500 internal server error message. Let me know please if you have another process.